# Possible to disable postback in a DOM element?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms, postback

I search to disable postback in a page of my ASP.NET WebForms application. This aspc page will be 100% javascript (with vue.js) and will contains no ASP.NET controls.

If I put an HTML button on it, I have to not forget to add a 'return false' in the onClick event. My goal is to not have to think about this.

Is it possible to disable postback on this special page ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to add an override to the click event to all elements. Since these events "stack", this should be added before any other click binding events.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('*').on('click', function(event) { event.preventDefault(); });
    });
</script>
```

This will also catch any elements that are added "dynamically". I have not investigated potential side effects of this method. But it does stop forms from submitting through button/link clicks with postback.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can prevent a page to post back. But you can one time use javascript on your body instead of all buttons:

```
<body onsubmit="return false;">
```

Answer (score -1):

Just use html pure html controls, avoid webcontrols or any html control with runat="server" on it